# Responsive design. Setting min-width in em

Tags: css, media-queries

First example :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
body { background-color: blue; }
}
```

Rule will work with extensions more screen 400px.

Today met a different style to set rules :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40em) {
body { background-color: blue; }
}
```

What is the idea of using 40em ...? It's not even a fixed width. Under what conditions will apply this rule?

When to use this rule?

Comment: Assuming any given pixel size makes sense as a breakpoint can be dangerous - particularly when text zooming, retina displays, etc. are involved. em-based queries are a way of changing the layout based on the amount of information (in the form of text) fits on the screen. There are many articles explaining this; here's a good one: http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Comment: Paul Roub thank you.